# Do WCF support Asynchronously operations' invoke within TransactionScope?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, transactionscope

I am trying out the WCF Transaction implementation and I come up with the idea that whether asynchronous transaction is supported by WCF 4.0.

for example, 
I have several service operations with client\service transaction enabled, in the client side, I use a TransactionScope and within the transaction, I create Tasks to asynchronously call those operations.

In this situation, I am assuming that the transaction is going to work correctly, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that very much. It appears that you if you are starting an ascync operation you are no longer participating on the original transaction.

I wrote a little LINQPad test

```
void Main()
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    {
    try
    {
        Transaction.Current.Dump("created");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Test);
        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Console.WriteLine("closed");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
}


public void Test()
{
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    {
    Transaction.Current.Dump("test start"); // null
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Transaction.Current.Dump("test end"); // null
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set both the OperationContext and Transaction.Current in the created Task.

More specifically, in the service you'll need to do like this:

```
public Task ServiceMethod() {
    OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
    Transaction transaction = Transaction.Current;

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
         OperationContext.Current = context;
         Transaction.Current = transaction;

         // your code, doing awesome stuff
    }
}
```

This gets repetitive as you might suspect, so I'd recommend writing a helper for it.